# "pip install requests" is returning "No module named 'requests'" on Python 3.11

Tags: python-3.x, pip, modulenotfounderror

I am new to Python and I have recently downloaded Python 3.11.  Somehow I managed to download an earlier version of 3.6.X as well, but I have uninstalled the older version and I have installed the requests package using the command "pip install requests".

I am trying to learn web-scraping in Python, but I am having an issue with the requests module not being found.

I have read over many articles stating that the PATH may not be correct (it wasn't but is now), there may be multiple versions installed (that was also true but has now been corrected), or that pip needed to be upgraded.

Nothing has seemed to work to this point.

I did (at one time) have Python 3.6.X installed as well but I uninstalled this version and made sure that my pip install was upgraded to the newest version.  I have also made sure the PATH is correct.

I am still having issues when trying to run "pip install requests" and I am getting an error stating "ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'requests'".

When I run "python3 -m pip list" in my cmd prompt, I can see requests is installed under version 2.28.1.

Is there anything else I am missing that could be causing a compatibility issue?

Comment: Post the full error messages. Also compare the outputs of `python3 --version` and `pip --version` to confirm that they match.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.